# How to implement a Sitecore workflow with the right users, roles and security?

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

To take this question clear, I take for this question the sample workflow delivered by Sitecore version 6.6.

In the Sitecore solution I have defined three roles (in order by a lot of permissions to low):

1. Administrator
2. Author
3. Blogger

*Ad 1. The administrator does have all permissions.*

*Ad 2. The author does have all permissions to create, edit and delete content, to publish the content - and to approve and disapprove content written by the blogger.*

*Ad 3. The blogger has only rights to create content under a specific path in the content three and only based on the Blog template. This user has no rights to publish content*

Now the problem. The user with role Author and Blogger cannot see the *workflow* ribbon in the *review* tab. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks a lot,
Jordy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please assign sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring role to Author and Blogger in Member of.

How? If you login and go to core database by appending ?sc_content=core in url and enter. Now you traverse to below item. Now click Assign command in Security Tab.

/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Workflow

You will see as below. Note: I checked this in Sitecore 8 Initial but hope this should be same for your version.

[image]